# How can I prevent OS to kill my MUSIC app (use MediaPlayer, service)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using Service in my MUSIC application and it needs to run until my application is destroyed, but the problem is it gets killed by OS (my phone runs android 4.2.2, and it has 128MB of RAM).so that The OS always kills the app service when I press HOME button or back button.

I have searched on stack overflow and tried this solution:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    notify("Service is StartCommanded");
    myplayer.start();
     return START_STICKY;
}
```

but the music restarts from the begin position, I don't want this to happen

Answer (score 0):

Granted that your service gets a new intent for every song it tries to play try to use the redeliver intent flag.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY

Keep in mind that this won't make your service restart in the same was as start sticky, as there is a maximum number of times it tries to restart it.

In onDestroy find out where you were in the music play back, store that value and seek to that position when you start your playback again.

Finally, if you're getting killed so fast by the system, you may need to optimize the memory consumption inside of your service.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem remember to accept the answer ;)

Comment: excuse me, I 'm a newbie, how to accept your answer ? :D

Comment: There is a checkbox next to it tick it :) also up vote if you think it was a good answer (press up arrow)

Comment: How do I test if I did make lower memory consumption?